# What is the bright spot in reflective digital holographic microscopy and how to remove it?

Tags: optics, microscopy, hologram

We are working on reflective DHM and the system looks like the setup in figure 1. We are facing a severe problem of reflection in the system.

Apart from the reference beam and object beam, there is an unknown strong spot on the CCD. In figure 2, the black bar is the object, the bright concentric spot is the reflection of the objective lens (if a plano-convex replaces the objective, the bright spot still exists). When the distance between the objective and condenser changes, the radius of the spot changes as well. We guess it originates from this lens, but we have no idea how to remove it.

In addition, in figure 3, the condenser is placed above the BS and the reference beam is blocked. The bright concentric spot changes to an interference pattern. Does anybody have any clue on this problem? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: difficult to solve remotely. what happens in fig.3 if you 1) change the distance objective-sample and 2) change alignemet objective-condenser?